# My application wont change its position according to the task bar position

Tags: winapi

My application window does not cover the task bar. When I launch the application, it works fine. After launching the application, when I change the position of the task bar, the application does not change accordingly. Is there a window message which notifies the change in task bar position so I can update my window?

Comment: I cannot understand the question

Answer (score 1):

When the taskbar is moved/resized, a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx) message with its `wParam` parameter set to `SPI_SETWORKAREA` is sent to all top-level windows.  You can then call [`SystemParametersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) with its `uiAction` parameter set to `SPI_GETWORKAREA` to retrieve the new dimensions of the work area (the area not covered by the taskbar or toolbars) of the primary monitor, then update your window to stay within that area as needed.  If you need to support work areas across multiple monitors, use [`GetMonitorInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144901.aspx) instead of `SystemParametersInfo()`.